# How to use String arrays from string.xml in android layouts?

Tags: android, arrays, android-layout, android-resources

I created a string-array in my strings.xml file and I want access array in
my layout to fill my chips. How can I do it?

**This my strings.xml**

```
<string-array name="shortcutCategoryNames">
    <item>Digital</item>
    <item>Clothes</item>
    <item>Sport</item>
    <item>Cosmetics</item>
</string-array>
```

**This is my layout**

```
        <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                android:id="@+id/chp_digital"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />
            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                android:id="@+id/chp_clothes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

         <!-- rest of Chips-->

        </com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>
```

Comment: "I want access array in my layout to fill my chips" -- there is no mechanism for doing that, sorry. You will need to use Java/Kotlin code to create your chips and put them in the group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get String Array using below method.

```
ArrayList<String> tagList = new ArrayList();

String[] someArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.shortcutCategoryNames);
tagList.addAll(Arrays.asList(someArray));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get `string-array` using this code:

```
String strArray[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array. shortcutCategoryNames);
```

Then loop through `strArray` to create `Chip` and add those `Chip` to `ChipGroup` programmatically